# How to post image (any type including gif) from my website to facebook without link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to post image from my website to facebook without source link, just image.

I try js sdk, but can't find solution for post images WITHOUT link.

Comment: That would be a _photo upload_ then. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook's Graph API User Photo Edge to publish photos to Facebook by attaching the photo as multipart/form-data. You can convert the image to dataUrl, format it & sent it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,

this code works for me:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me/photos','post',
        {
            message: 'Message',
            display: 'iframe',
            url: 'https://sample.jpg'
        },
        function(response) {}
        );
    }
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

also I use FB.ui(), also works with images (only share page with image, without adding image to facebook album):

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'share',
   display: 'popup',
   href: 'page.url',
   picture: 'https://sample.jpg'
}, function(response){});
```

But now problem is in sharing animated gif, if I use just gif as "url" (in first example) or "picture" (in second example), I see just image on facebook, but I need ANIMATEd gif.
I could use this code:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'share',
   display: 'popup',
   href: 'animated.gif',
}, function(response){});
```

But in this case I see source link on facebook, it's problem for me, because source images will be removed.